# How to hide div in slider in module in Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity-5

I have a slider in module like this repeated div in slider.

```
 <div class="bottom-slider item" >
    <a class="img" href='<%# Eval("Article4").ToString()!="" ? Eval("Article4") : Eval("ArticleL4").ToString()!="" ? PageManager.GetManager().GetPageNode(Guid.Parse(Eval("ArticleL4").ToString())).GetUrl().Replace("~/","") : "#" %>'>
          <sf:ImageAssetsField runat="server" DataFieldName="ArticleImage4" IsThumbnail="False" />
           </a>
        <div class="slide-txt-box">
        <sf:SitefinityLabel runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ArticleTitle4")%>'  WrapperTagName="h6" HideIfNoText="true"  />
        <p><sf:SitefinityLabel runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ArticleText4")%>' HideIfNoText="true"  /></p>
        <a href='<%# Eval("Article4").ToString()!="" ? Eval("Article4") : Eval("ArticleL4").ToString()!="" ? PageManager.GetManager().GetPageNode(Guid.Parse(Eval("ArticleL4").ToString())).GetUrl().Replace("~/","") : "#" %>'>Read more</a>
        </div>
        </div>
```

I want when "ArticleTitle4" text is null div is not show in slider.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your:

```
<div class="bottom-slider item" >
```

To some thing like:

```
<div class="bottom-slider item" runat="server" id="myDiv" visible='<% !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Article4"))%>'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<div class="bottom-slider item" >
    <a class="img" href='<%# Eval("Article4").ToString()!="" ? Eval("Article4") : Eval("ArticleL4").ToString()!="" ? PageManager.GetManager().GetPageNode(Guid.Parse(Eval("ArticleL4").ToString())).GetUrl().Replace("~/","") : "#" %>'>
          <sf:ImageAssetsField runat="server" DataFieldName="ArticleImage4" IsThumbnail="False" />
           </a>
        <div class="slide-txt-box" style='display:<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Eval("ArticleTitle4")) ? "none" : "block" %>'>
        <sf:SitefinityLabel runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ArticleTitle4")%>'  WrapperTagName="h6" HideIfNoText="true"  />
        <p><sf:SitefinityLabel runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ArticleText4")%>' HideIfNoText="true"  /></p>
        <a href='<%# Eval("Article4").ToString()!="" ? Eval("Article4") : Eval("ArticleL4").ToString()!="" ? PageManager.GetManager().GetPageNode(Guid.Parse(Eval("ArticleL4").ToString())).GetUrl().Replace("~/","") : "#" %>'>Read more</a>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Hope this helps!